# Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: inputParameters

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I am getteing "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: inputParameters" while trying to create a pipeline using the azure devops REST APIs. o

Can anybody suggest what should be the request body parameters for the API Call.

My Implemetation:

```
API CALL (POST) : https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/pipelines?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

> Request Body:

```
{
    "configuration": [
        {
            "type": "yaml",
            "folder": "./",
            "name": "trl-pipeline"
        }
    ]
}
```

as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

> Response:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: inputParameters",
    "typeName": "System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib",
    "typeKey": "ArgumentNullException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 0
}
```

Comment: As I read the documentation, the `folder` and `name` fields should go up a level to be siblings of `configuration`. You could also create a pipeline in the UI then `GET` that with an http request and see how it is structured, to verify this.

Comment: Thanks @TomW, I am new to this and it helped me to learn where to look in such issues. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add repository id and name in your request body. Here is my sample:

1.I created a yaml file in my azure repos.

[image]

2.My request body looks like this:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines?api-version=6.0-preview.1



{
        "configuration":{
            "path": "azure-pipelines.yml",
            "repository":{
                "id": "{repo id}",
                "type": "azureReposGit",
                "name": "{repo name}"
            },
            "type":"yaml"
        },
        "name":"PipelineName"   
    }
```

Comment: @Abhineet Chaudhary I am glad to know that it is useful to you. You could accept it as answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, posting a blank body worked

`POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/preview?api-version=6.0-preview`

```
{
}
```